# How to extract field from JSON file with Gatling

Tags: json, scala, gatling, jsonpath, findall

**I'm new in Gatling and Scala.**
I'm trying to write scenarios to test an API and do some http requests.
I have a JSON file with an array of object.
I'd like to extract the ID field in order to achieve an http request with it (multiple get). I'm trying to use feeder, i'm not sure about how it's working.

Here is my code :

```
val jsonFileFeeder = jsonFile("test.json")

  val scn = scenario("Http mget document").feed(jsonFileFeeder)
    .repeat(requests, "i") {
      exec(http("document:mget")
        .post("http://" + host + ":7512/index/collection/_mGet")
        .header("something", jwt)
        .body(StringBody(""" \"ids\": $[id]"""))
        .check(jsonPath("$.._id[*]").findAll.saveAs("id"))
        .check(status.is(200))
      )
    }
```

So basically, i'm trying to get the ids from the file (the field is "_id") and save it.

```
.check(jsonPath("$.._id[*]").findAll.saveAs("id"))
```

As you may guess, this isn't working, and i've this error :

`10:00:52.115 [WARN ] i.g.h.e.r.DefaultStatsProcessor - Request` `'document:mget' failed for user 1: jsonPath($.._id[*]).findAll.exists, found nothing`

My json file is like this :

```
[
    {
         "requestId":"99999",
         "status":200,
     ///...///
         "result":
         {
             "_id":"95F8NF",
             "_version":1,
    ///...///
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your JsonPath is wrong. It should just be

```
.check(jsonPath("$.._id").findAll.saveAs("id"))
```

`[*]` is used when you are iterating over an array. But specifying `..` means that you are saying to the program to reach all the depths it can.